# How to access properties on a dynamically created component in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

How can I access a component's properties when that component was created dynamically at runtime? When creating a component in markup I can simply `bind:someProperty={someVariable}`, but I don't know of any way to do this when the component is instantiated using `new Component()` at runtime? How can I get access to this new component's properties?

`App.svelte`:

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from "svelte";
    
    import Component2 from "./Component2.svelte";
    
    let taken;
    
    let container;
    
    onMount(() => {
        new Component2({
            target: container
        });
        
        // How do I access this new component's `someValue` property?
    });
    
</script>

<div bind:this={container}>
    
</div>

<Component2 bind:someValue={taken}></Component2>
```

`Component2.svelte`:

```
<script>
    export const someValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8999 + 1000);
</script>

<p>
    {someValue}
</p>
```

I know that I can pass in a `props: {}` object to the constructor to *assign* values to the properties, but what I want is to have the component assign its own values to the properties and just be able to *access* them from outside the component.

Is this considered bad practice and a "not Svelte-like" approach? Should I be using a store instead? If so, what should that look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use bindings in code, but you can read the values given that you set an [option](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-svelte-options) in the component. Add this to the component file:

```html
<svelte:options accessors />
```

That way you can store the reference and access the property:

```js
const component = new Component2({
    target: container
});

const value = component.someValue;
```

As for whether this is a good idea, I would only construct components in code when there is a good reason to. E.g. it may makes sense for a modal dialog that  is added temporarily and whose state is disposed of after use anyway.

Comment: This perfectly answers my question, thank you.